# View desktop whitout lose the windows positions

Tags: windows

its posible minimize all windows in windows 10, something similar to [windows + d], open any file, and return all windows??

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/shell/ishelldispatch4-toggledesktop).